# Parameter binding in WebApi post method

Tags: c#, http-post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, frombodyattribute

I am unable to bind data to the locationModel parameter in the following method. I looked at other posts but no solution seems to be working:

```
// Web Api Post method

public HttpResponseMessage Post(string vin, [FromBody] LocationModel locationModel)
{
    return null;
}
```

I am invoking the method through fiddler in the following manner:

[image]

The method is called upon executing the post request but the LocationModel is null. Here is the definition for the LocationModel:

```
public class LocationModel
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public DateTime LogTimestamp { get; set; }

    public float Latitude { get; set; }

    public float Longitude { get; set; }

    public decimal OdometerReading { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastUpdatedTimestamp { get; set; }

    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is slightly malformed - you have

```
"Url" = "http://localhost...",
```

rather than

```
"Url" : "http://localhost...",
```

i.e. you have `=` instead of `:`